# Firefox - org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, serenity-bdd

I have faced a weird situation, where on the page in Serenity I have to scroll to the element:

```
withAction().moveToElement(webElement).perform();
```

and this method for some elements throws:

```
org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: 
(377.375, 958.3999938964844) is out of bounds of viewport width (1268) and height (943)
```

---

It happens only in Firefox(Chrome works fine). Moreover almost all other places, where I'm using the same method are working well. All elements are just usual elements like buttons, input fields, etc.

Does anybody know how to fix this in Firefox?

I have:

- Firefox 61.0.2 (64-bit)
- Windows 10
- Serenity 1.9.30
- Geckodriver 0.21.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: 
(377.375, 958.3999938964844) is out of bounds of viewport width (1268) and height (943)
```

...implies that *Selenium* was unable to focus on the desired element as the element was out of bounds of the viewport.

Your main issue is the *WebElement* identified as **webElement** is out of [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) so *Selenium* can't move the **focus** on the desired element through `moveToElement()` method.

### Solution

A simple solution would be to use the `executeScript()` method to bring the desired element within the *viewport* and then invoke `moveToElement()` method as follows:

```
WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_of_element"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", myElement);
withAction().moveToElement(webElement).perform();
```