# org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: move target out of bounds using Selenium Chrome and java.version: '16.0.2'

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, java-16, selenium-edgedriver

I am trying to click a link that is on a dropdown menu. This dropdown menu appears when I hover over a button. Right now, my test crashes with a `MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException`, which happens when I try to hover the button. When I open the page in my browser, I have no trouble finding or hovering over the button, as it doesn't seem to be outside of the viewport by any means.
The code I use to hover the button is:

```
private void hoverButtonWaitDropDown(WebElement button) {
        a.moveToElement(button).build().perform();
        try {
            w.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(dropDownMenu));
        } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
            ExtentTestManager.log(logger, Level.WARN, "Dropdown menu failed to display");
        }
    }
```

Then, the test waits for the dropdown menu to appear and loops through the available options to find the desired one, and finally clicks it:

```
public void clickContextSetting(String setting) {
        hoverButtonWaitDropDown(contextButton);
        if (dataItems.size() == 0) {
            ExtentTestManager.log(logger, Level.WARN, "There are no context settings on the dropdown menu");
            return;
        }
        for (WebElement con : dataItems) {
            if (con.findElement(By.tagName("span")).getText().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(setting)) {
                con.click();
                return;
            }
        }
        Assert.fail("Test aborted because context setting: " + setting + " is not present on the topbar dropdown menu");
    }
```

Now, when I comment out `a.moveToElement(button).build().perform();` , run the test and move the mouse to the button myself in order to display the dropdown menu, the test is terminated instead by the `Assert.fail()` call. This means that the test does find a list of links, since `dataItems.size() == 0` evaluates to false, but it is unable to find the desired link on the dropdown menu. I have added a print method to print the text of all the links on the dropdown menu that appears:

```
private void printDataItems() {
        for (WebElement item: dataItemsText) {
            System.out.println(item.getText());
        }
    }
```

but that just prints 5 empty `Strings`.
When I look for the elements that contain the link texts on the dropdown menu in devTools with the selector `div[class='dataitems'] a span`, it lists all the links and highlights the link texts like it should, but it doesn't work when I try it with Selenium.

The text nodes look like this:

[span](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlhYk.png)

I have manually checked all my locators, and they are all correct, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.
I should note that I run into this issue with chromedriver (96) and edgedriver (95), but not with geckodriver (94). When I run this test with geckodriver, the test script correctly hovers the button, prints out all the available links on the dropdown menu and clicks the link. Any ideas?

Edit:
As requested, here are the locators for the WebElements that I refer to in my question:

```
@FindBy(css = "div[gadget-name='Topbar context btn']")
private WebElement contextButton;

@FindBy(css = "div[class^='dropdata']")
private WebElement dropDownMenu;

@FindBy(css = "div[class='dataitems'] a")
private List<WebElement> dataItems;

@FindBy(css = "div[class='dataitems'] a span")
private List<WebElement> dataItemsText;
```

And the stacktrace of the MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException (I'm assuming it is this):

```
org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: move target out of bounds
  (Session info: chrome=95.0.4638.69)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-I6V1OLJ', ip: '192.168.2.8', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '16.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 95.0.4638.69, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 95.0.4638.17 (a9d0719444d4b..., userDataDir: C:\Users\mb_vl\AppData\Loca...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:59476}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 6003d76fccdd4ddbed789b440fa9e6f7
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.perform(RemoteWebDriver.java:618)
at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions$BuiltAction.perform(Actions.java:639)
at ObjectRepository.items.topbar_improved.hoverButtonWaitDropDown(topbar_improved.java:65)
at ObjectRepository.items.topbar_improved.clickContextSetting(topbar_improved.java:500)
at test_classes.general_scenarios.topbar_general.checkModal(topbar_general.java:50)
at test_classes.pages_local.local_test.topBar_clickLastLogins_modalIsDisplayed(local_test.java:102)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:132)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:599)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:174)
at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:822)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:147)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:764)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:585)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1218)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1069)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1037)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:284)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:119)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:428)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:562)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:548)
```

## Edit: solved

I contacted our frontend dev, and they asked to try it on the production environment. It worked there, and after some searching I noticed that the containing element that I was trying to interact with had `zoom: 90%`. I ran my test, paused it and set the element `zoom` to 100% in devTools, and continued execution; everything worked again.
I did some digging, and apparently this is a known thing: [link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=628)

Comment: You should show code that locates "contextButton", "dropDownMenu","dataItems", and "dataItemsText".  (The first part of your question will concern "contextButton"... the 2nd part seems to be related to waiting for visibility only (that may not be enough), and probably only on the container for the spans... )

Comment: I have updated my question with the code you requested.

Comment: Error stack trace of `MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: I have also added the stacktrace now.

Comment: for the 2nd part you may want to include the HTML of one of the <span> tags you're trying to getText() from.  The fact that you don't get a Stale Element exception suggests that there is another node in there.  Or, to troubleshoot, check: System.out.println(item.getAttribute('innerHTML'));

Comment: Added an image of the HTML per your request; there doesn't seem to be another node..

Answer (score 3):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException:
```

...implies that [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) was unable to focus on the desired element as the element was out of bounds of the viewport.

Your main issue is the *WebElement* identified as ***button*** is out of [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) so *Selenium* can't move the **focus** on the desired element through `moveToElement()` method.

---

### Solution

A simple solution would be to use the `scrollIntoView()` method to bring the desired element within the *viewport* and then invoke `moveToElement()` method as follows:

```
WebElement myElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(button));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", myElement);
a.moveToElement(webElement).build().perform();
```

### Update

A conservative suggestion would be replace *`java.version: '16.0.2'`* with stable latest [***JDK 8u311***](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) as earlier we have faced the following issues of Selenium with higher Java versions:

- [An illegal reflective access operation has occurred while executing automated tests using Selenium and Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58100247/an-illegal-reflective-access-operation-has-occurred-while-executing-automated-te/58132830#58132830)
- [Unable to import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver using Selenium and Java 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876955/unable-to-import-org-openqa-selenium-webdriver-using-selenium-and-java-11/54880228#54880228)
- [Does Selenium v3.141 support Java 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58531018/does-selenium-v3-141-support-java-13/58538235#58538235)
- ["java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class org.apache.bsf.BSFManager not in module" error with ChromeDriver Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59171497/java-lang-module-invalidmoduledescriptorexception-provider-class-org-apache-bs/59173119#59173119)

---

### References

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [Firefox - org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52116195/firefox-org-openqa-selenium-interactions-movetargetoutofboundsexception/52117023#52117023)
- [org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: (x, y) is out of bounds while MouseHover with GeckoDriver Firefox Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55413422/org-openqa-selenium-interactions-movetargetoutofboundsexception-x-y-is-out-o/55416099#55416099)

Comment: Doesn't `moveToElement()` already take care of scrolling the item into view?

Comment: It would only if the element is visible and within the viewport.

Comment: I assume then that there's a difference between an element being within the viewport, and me being able to see it on the screen? Also, I have tried your solution, and I still get a `MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: I appreciate your input, but I want to avoid switching JDKs for now. Tomorrow I have a meeting with out front-end developer to see if they have any insights, I will get back to you after that.

Comment: Solved! I updated my question with my solution,

Comment: the key is that when Selenium gets a position of an object it gets the bounding rectangle... those coords change based on scroll position.  When you use Selenium's click() method it will automatically scroll the element into view before getting the location.  When actionschain is used I don't think it will scroll the element into view first... so the returned x,y position can be offscreen.  The zoom setting may have pushed the center of the element offscreen.

Comment: From [docs](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#moveToElement(org.openqa.selenium.WebElement)): "Moves the mouse to the middle of the element. **The element is scrolled into view** and its location is calculated using getClientRects."

Answer (score 1):

With the following implementation, you will get to see the element in the browser and resolves this error.

It uses the [scrollByAmount](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/wheel/#scroll-by-given-amount) method.

```java
public static WebElement scrollToElement(WebElement elementToScroll, WebDriver webDriver) {

    Rectangle rect = elementToScroll.getRect();
    int deltaY = rect.y + rect.height;
    new Actions(webDriver)
      .scrollByAmount(0, deltaY)
      .perform();
    return elementToScroll;

}
```

Ps: The `MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: move target out of bounds`
can be seen when using the `moveToElement` or `scrollToElement` method.
My best guess is that this function scrolls to the element but only to the top position of the bounding rectangle, making the element not visible.